# Verificação de números repetidos em PHP

Tags: php, loop

Estou fazendo um trabalho da escolha que é uma loteria.
Nessa loteria eu preciso verificar se os números são iguais, se forem, devo substituir por outro número e esse número não pode ter sido já gerado. Minha dificuldade é conseguir fazer um laço de repetição que verifique sempre isso. Segue abaixo a linha do código:

Ps: O algoritmo é pra ser rodado no prompt de comando mesmo

- `$numDezenas`: Quantidade de dezenas que ele quer apostar (Megasena,
  Lotomania, Quina e Lotofácil)
- `$apostas`: Quantidade de apostas
- `$numMax`: Valor máximo que pode ser gerado pelo sorteio de acordo com
  o tipo de aposta (Megasena é 60, Quina 80, etc.)

```
function dezenas($numDezenas,$apostas, $numMax){

    $dezenas = [];
    $numDezenas = $numDezenas - 1;
    for ($i=0; $i < $apostas ; $i++) { //Quantidade de apostas 
        for ($j=0; $j <= $numDezenas; $j++) { //Quantidade de Dezenas
            $dezenas[$j] = rand(0, $numMax);
            for ($k=$numDezenas; $k > 0; $k--) { //Verificar se as dezenas são repetidas
                do {
                if ($dezenas[$j] == $dezenas[$k] && $j != $k) {
                    $dezenas[$j] = rand(0,$numMax);
                    } while (); //Aqui que não sei o que fazer...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se é exatamente o que você quer, mas fiz um exemplo simples.

Pode ver o script funcionando no [ideone.](http://ideone.com/Zwpycm)

Obs: usei o `str_pad` pra preencher os valores que tem apenas um digito com 0 a esquerda para ficar no padrão da loteria, segue um exemplo para gerar os números:

```
<?php
function apostar($qtdDeDezenas, $qtdDeApostas, $numMaximoDezena){
    $apostas = [];
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $qtdDeApostas; $i++) {
        $dezenas = [];
        for ($j = 1; $j <= $qtdDeDezenas; $j++) {
            while (count($dezenas) < $qtdDeDezenas) {
                $dezenaGerada = str_pad(rand(0, $numMaximoDezena), 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
                if (!in_array($dezenaGerada, $dezenas)) {
                    $dezenas[] = $dezenaGerada;
                }
            }
        }

        sort($dezenas, SORT_NUMERIC); // ordernar da dezena menor para maior
        $apostas[]['dezenas'] = $dezenas;
    }

    return $apostas;
}

$qtdDeDezenas = 6;
$qtdDeApostas = 15;
$numMaximoDezena = 60;

$apostas = apostar($qtdDeDezenas, $qtdDeApostas, $numMaximoDezena);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($apostas);
echo "<pre>";
```

Comment: Quase isso... Notei que a posição dos arrays equivale ao número, queria que iniciasse no 0, mas o ruim é que não consigo entender a lógica de organizar os números sem que eles se repitam na mesma aposta...

Comment: Você pode usar a função in_array e verificar se a dezena que você gerou já esta no array de dezenas, caso não esteja, você coloca.

Editei a resposta conforme vc quer.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro acredito que seja melhor dividir isto em várias funções, uma função como o nome sugere deve fazer uma única função.

Entretanto você pode simplesmente utilizar o `count()` com o `array_unique()` e utilizando o `sort()` para manter mesma ordem, por questão de performance isto não é ideal, entretanto é simples de entender o conceito.

```
function removerDuplicidade(array $array)
{

    sort($array);
    return array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);

}

function criarAposta(int $quantidadeDeDezenasParaMarcar, int $numeroMaximoDisponivelNaCartela)
{

    $aposta = [];

    while (count($aposta) < $quantidadeDeDezenasParaMarcar) {

        $aposta[] = random_int(0, $numeroMaximoDisponivelNaCartela);
        $aposta = removerDuplicidade($aposta);

    }

    return $aposta;

}
```

A ideia é simples, cada número gerado pelo `random_int`, **requer PHP 7**, será "filtrado" pelo `removerDuplicidade`, ele é responsável por manter a ordem crescente (devido ao `sort()`) e irá remover as duplicidades devido ao `array_unique()`.

Supondo que ele gere três número:

```
$aposta = [1, 10, 20];
```

Suponha que ele gere `10`, que já existe, este número será removido pelo `array_unique`. Como o `while` é definido pelo `count()` a contagem se manterá `3`, uma vez que o quarto número foi removido.

---

Entretanto você precisa gerar mais de um, por isso pode utilizar uma nova função, bem parecida **como complemento**:

```
function criarMultiplasApostas(int $quantidadeDeApostas, int $quantidadeDeDezenas, int $numeroMaximoDisponivelNaCartela)
{

    $multiplasApostas = [];

    while (count($multiplasApostas) < $quantidadeDeApostas) {

        $multiplasApostas[] = criarAposta($quantidadeDeDezenas, $numeroMaximoDisponivelNaCartela);

        $multiplasApostas = removerDuplicidade($multiplasApostas);

    }

    return $multiplasApostas;

}
```

Isto irá fazer com que gere várias apostas, supondo que gerem duas:

```
$multiplasApostas = [
    [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    [1,2,3,4,5,6]
];
```

Isto seria removido pelo `removerDuplicidade`, porque são apostas idênticas, por essa razão é utilizado o `sort` para que eles sejam sempre na mesma ordem e por isso sejam removidos.

---

### **[Teste isto aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/047ac17064147d2613f2b66fbe183004f8c7703d)**

---

> **/!\ Falhas**

Uma das falhas é que pode ser que tente fazer:

```
gerarMultiplasApostas(100, 6, 7);
```

Isso é gerar 100 apostas com 6 números cada em um espaço de 8 números (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8). Isso é matematicamente impossível, o calculo de combinações é exatamente:

```
8! / (6! * (8 - 6)!)
```

Logo apenas existem `28` combinações, definir o `100` irá criar um loop infinito, que inclusive seria possível um DoS, pois cada processo ficaria travado por 30 segundos, por padrão.

Uma outra falha é que o `removerDuplicidade` não irá funcionar fora de ordem, sendo o `sort` extremamente necessário para gerar as apostas.